# how to extend complexType but have no children elements in subtype?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I currently have the following part of an xsd...

```
<xs:element name="requestExtension">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="abstractRequest"> 
                <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="unusedReqPart" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>   
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I need the requestExtension to extend abstractRequest but how do I get rid of the unusedReqPart so my jaxb generation still works?

EDIT for clarity: I "want" the elements of the super class to be included.  I do not want to remove them.  I only want the subtype's element above called "unusedReqPart" to be removed.  I only put it there temporarily so that my jaxb stuff compiles correctly.  I have it adhering to an existing protocol already by using minOccurs="0" there as that element is never used(so I would prefer to completely remove it if I can).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost feels like a trick question... Unless the language is what it is, then it is as simple as:

```
<xs:element name="requestExtension"> 
    <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:complexContent> 
            <xs:extension base="abstractRequest"/>
        </xs:complexContent> 
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

There is no reason why you wouldn't extend it using the "empty" particle. In turn, it allows you to have a concrete (hence usable) type without any new content on top of the base type.

I am sure you wouldn't want to go with the restriction (as described in one the answers); the effect there it is that it wipes out the entire content model (effectively makes it empty).

I would be surprised to hear that JAXB wouldn't work with I am proposing above; if you find it doesn't, please update your post with the particular version number of JAXB you're using, and a snippet of the generated class that doesn't pass your validation.

Comment: okay, I feel real stupid...I thought I tried that or saw an error or soemthing but it's working today...oh well.  thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could split abstractRequest in 2 types, one (A) extending the other (B), where A defines the part only needed for A. Your requestExtension then can extend B and thus won't have the unwanted parts.

Comment: My abstractRequest(not shown here) has 4 elements and I want those elements as part of this(which is only part of the reason I extend it).  I just want to remove the unusedReqPart element above, not create more types.

Answer (score 0):

When you would want to restrict the elements from parent, you should use as below:

```
<xs:restriction base="abstractRequest">
   <xs:sequence>

  </xs:sequence>
</xs:restriction>
```

That would stop the elements from being generated in children from parent.

Comment: I "want" to inherit all elements in the super type.  I only don't want that unusedReqPart that you see defined there is all.  I want the subtype though and the subtype should just have the supertype's elemetns is all.  how to do that?